# Concatenating a range from a signal

Tags: vhdl

Say i had 2 signals and i wanted to concatenate a range from both signals how can i do it?

Thanks

```
signal RandomSignal: std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
signal RandomSignal2: std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);

RandomSignal(between 0 and 5) & RandomSignal2(between 6 and 9)
```

Comment: Define signals and use dB

Comment: Sorry i dont understand could you explain it?

Comment: Define your specs first

Comment: Okay so how to concatenate after?

Comment: I am not familiar with specification!

Comment: Then define goals for all inputs and output

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/vectorconcatenate.html

Comment: Did you try `RandomSignal(5 downto 0) & RandomSignal2(9 downto 6)`?

Comment: Can you explain how this is an EE question? For example, a question on how to use an electric kettle to boil water doesn't make it an EE question on this site. Neither does how to merge portions of two signals together (in a soft way) just because the signals may be somewhat electric in origin.

Comment: OP is asking about VHDL. OP, you need to better outline the context around your question. Giving people a good context of what you are asking is the first step in asking good questions. If I just ask out of the blue "I need help understanding the matrix" it means completely different things if depending on whether it is a movie context or a math context.

Comment: Was this question edited? What's going on with the responses? It's tagged VHDL and has definitions of the 2 signals. Aren't basic VHDL operations on topic?

Comment: @Justin I think some people didn't know it was VHDL and OP was not knowledgeable enough to know they were talking about a different topic or confident enough refute what they were saying so things immediately went off on a tangent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
NewSignal(5 downto 0) <= RandomSignal(5 downto 0);
NewSignal(9 downto 6) <= RandomSignal2(9 downto 6);
```

Or swap things around like this:

```
NewSignal(5 downto 0) <= RandomSignal2(9 downto 6);
NewSignal(9 downto 6) <= RandomSignal(5 downto 0);
```

You may also interleave things arbitrarily like this:

```
NewSignal <= (0=>RandomSignal(9), 1=>RandomSignal2(4), others => '0');
```

And if you are brave you can reverse the order of the bits:

```
NewSignal(5 downto 0) <= RandomSignal(6 to 9);
```

Although the `std_logic_vector` for `RandomSignal` might have to have been declared using `to` instead of `downto` for this to be allowed. Either way, be vigilant when mixing `downto` and `to`. Some say never use `to` at all, unless you are interfacing with some code where an idiot who should be shot used `to` thereby forcing you to use `to`.

You my also find the property useful:

```
Some_std_logic_vector'Length
```

Comment: `'Length` does return the length, not the length - 1.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Does it? Because in a piece of code I just wrote last week I initially wrote it like that but it did not behave that way and I had to add the +1 modifier. I'll have to take a closer look.

Comment: @BrianDrummond My memory was off. I needed a zero-starting count so I subtracted 1 since it was returning the number of elements.

Answer (score -1):

Concatenation here could be the matrix multiplication of input with N=Numerator and D= Denominator you may consider. but there are other choices.

Port_1 — Concatenation of input signals
scalar | vector | matrix | N-D array

These are your choices and I previously posted link to explain the process.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/vectorconcatenate.html
For logic, which do you think is the best choice?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation

Comment: Why would concatenation mean that?????

Comment: It is just a logical way of stringing sources together according to specs.

Comment: You are too old Tony

Comment: True , my concatenation only involved spreadsheet strings of text arranged in some combined order. Which may be assigned numbers, which is just as unique as this problem and not the general case